# Converting from SQL raw query to GORM

Tags: orm, go-gorm

I wrote a SQL query to design an ORM. Now, I am trying to convert this query to [GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html). I read the documentation but I didn't make a proper decision if I use Clouse or conditions.

This is the SQL query I am intending to convert

```sql
select collection, count(*) as item_count from collections group by collection order by item_count desc, collection
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```golang
db.Select("collection", "count(*) as item_count").Group("collection").Order("item_count desc, collection").Find(&results)
```

should do the trick. Is that what you are looking for? If not, please comment and clarify.

Comment: Hey, I liked the answer. Maybe there's a problem with the section or it's the way I use it. I can't put `item_count` instead of `count`. It doesn't appear it's value inside of the response either.


`type Collections struct {
 Team string
 Count int }`